# Is there a way to allow my list's create form (which is customized using power app) to support managed metadata field which allow multiple values

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, list-form, modern-experience, powerapp

I have a custom list and this custom list has a managed metadata filed which have a hierarchy in its terms + allow multiple values, as follow:-

[image]

Now when i create a power app's create form, the managed metadata field will be **rendered as a drop-down without any hierarchy and without the ability to select multiple values**. as follow:-

[image]

so can anyone advice if power apps allow us to have a managed metadata which have a hierarchy in its terms + allow multiple values?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In PowerApps managed metadata column shows up as a drop-down menu and There is no (out of the box) way to show the "tree structure" of terms.

   **Source**: [PowerApps and managed metadata](https://alberthoitingh.com/2019/07/09/powerapps-and-managed-metadata/).
2. Multi-valued managed metadata columns are fully supported in PowerApps.

   **Source**: [Tips and Tricks for multiselect controls with advanced tagging options](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/News-Announcements/Tips-and-Tricks-for-multiselect-controls-with-advanced-tagging/ba-p/91130).